# How to register the value of numericUpDown before a change?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm rather new to C#, (using Visual Studio) and have several numericUpDown used on a form, the numeric range of these are 8 to 15.

When you change the value in these numericUpDown, raising the value will incur a point cost, decreasing the value will add points... as the cost differs the higher you get, I'm trying to register the value before the change, unfortunately I have no clue how I can manage this.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Add some code examples and tag a technology you refer to. `C#` is not enough - is it ASP.NET, WPF, Forms, or ...

Comment: @TarasB , i have googled this, it is a `windows form control`, need to tag this to windows form.

Comment: MSDN link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "Before" is very murky.  Consider the Enter event, fired when the user navigates to the NUD.

Comment: This link might be useful -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369670/how-to-validate-numericupdown-when-value-change-and-not-lost-focus, also check this - http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?449134-2005-NumericUpDown-Old-Value-vs-New-Value-Question

Answer (score 2):

```
private int numericValue = 8;

private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //numericValue holds the before value
    ...
    numericValue = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
}
```

Comment: That would give the new value, not the one that was before change.

Comment: @26071986 You are downvoting too easy. The code whould give the before value. When we enter the *numericUpDown1_ValueChanged* function, *numericValue* **is** the before value. We use it and in the end *numericValue = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;* we change it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, it's relatively simple, should work pretty nicely without any problems:

```
//First, store your values in an array, just a small one
int[] values = {0, 0};

//Then, when the value of the NumericUpDown is changed, move the values around the array
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    values[0] = values[1];
    values[1] = numericUpDown1.Value;
}
```

When the program first starts, the array will be initialized to `0, 0` and your NumericUpDown should have a value of `0`. Let's have a look at what happens when we change the value of the NumericUpDown.

Before we change the value, the array's value is `0, 0`. When we change it, the last `0` at index `1` of the array get's moved to index `0`, and the current value of the NumericUpDown get's moved to index `1`. Say we changed the value to 55, the array's value is now `0, 55`. Say we change it again, to 68. The array's value is now `55, 68`. The old value of the array is stored at index `0` of the array at all times.

If you want your NumericUpDown to have a default value that differs from `0`, just change the initialization of the array, to reflect the default value of your NumericUpDown. Say if you wanted the default value to be `100`, the array should be initialized with:

```
int[] values = {0, 100};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve old value with numericUpDown1.**Text** in numericUpDown1_ValueChanged

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
private void nud_splitOrder_ordersQuantaty_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var senderObject = (NumericUpDown)sender;
    MessageBox.Show($"from {((UpDownBase)sender).Text} to {senderObject.Value}");
}
```